# regex that does not allow comma blank together

Tags: html, regex

I have a html input field, which shall not be able to allow `", "` (comma and blank space after comma) via the pattern tag but comma and blank extra should be allowed

Looks like these:

```
<input type="text" name="ausg" pattern="" title="xx">
```

Comment: what does "comma and blank extra" mean?

Comment: post an example. It's unclear.

Comment: An example could be `Hello, StackOverflow` where after hello there is a comma and a blank space after that.

Comment: Yeah like Sid Ms example.
Allowed:"Hallo Tom,Black" 
Not allowed: "Hallo Tom, Black"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^$|^[\w,]+$
```

The `^` and `$` match the beginning and the end of the text.

Use `\w` that include `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

`,` Match a Comma.

`+` 1 or more.

**UPDATE**

```
^[\w\s]+(?:,[^\s]+)?$
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LjpMJ/1/)**

Comment: Thanks, its nearly perfect, but with your answer a blank isn't accepted, but i want that it is allowed

Comment: Sorry, but still when i typ in "Hello World" false appears(in your Link)